# File permission issue - You need permission to perform this action

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, rdp, file-permissions, ntfs, dfs

This is a very strange issue related to a dfs replicated folder.

The share in question is shared with "Everyone" with full access and permissions are applied to sub-folders using ACLs.  Three groups are applied to each folder (Full access to a file administrators group, Read and execute access to a Read only group and Modify access to a Read/Write group).

All is fine in terms of creating/modifying files for the staff that have Read/Write.  The issue occurs when staff that have Read/Write access try to delete a file which shows the dreaded "You need permission to perform this action".  This occurs even if the file was created by the user in question.  Looking at effective permissions shows the correct level of access for the user in question.

What is even more strange is that usually, staff will access these shares using an RDP session which is where the issue occurs.  However, if the share is accessed directly under the same user, the file can be deleted.

My first thought was a permission issue but I'm not convinced of that now as files are able to be deleted under certain circumstances i.e. directly through the UNC path.

Any thoughts would be most welcome.